# Why can't I watch multiple files in a for loop in swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm using DispatchSource API to watch changes of my file system in my macOS app. when I do it one by one it works, however when I do it in a for in loop it doesn't work. Why is it like this ? Aren't they just the same ?

This is not working, file descriptors are correct but `setEventHandler` will never be called

```
func watch(onFsChange: @escaping () -> Void) {

        for fileDescriptor in self.fileDescriptors {
            source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: fileDescriptor, eventMask: fsEvent, queue: queue)

            source?.setEventHandler {
                FSWatcher.updateStatus()
                onFsChange()
            }

            source?.setCancelHandler {
                close(fileDescriptor)
            }

            source?.resume()
        }

    }
```

This is working, `setEventHandler` is called when there is any change in the paths

```
func watch(onFsChange: @escaping () -> Void) {

        source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: self.fileDescriptors[0], eventMask: fsEvent, queue: queue)

        source?.setEventHandler {
            FSWatcher.updateStatus()
            onFsChange()
        }

        source?.setCancelHandler {
            close(self.fileDescriptors[0])
        }

        source?.resume()



        source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: self.fileDescriptors[1], eventMask: fsEvent, queue: queue)

        source?.setEventHandler {
            FSWatcher.updateStatus()
            onFsChange()
        }

        source?.setCancelHandler {
            close(self.fileDescriptors[1])
        }

        source?.resume()


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning your `source` property with new `DispatchSourceFileSystemObject` each time, though previously assigned source gets deallocated. I suggest that in first case the last fileDescriptor is pointing to something never changed, and in second case fileDescriptors[1] is something changed frequently.
The decision is to make `var sources = [DispatchSourceFileSystemObject]()` instead of single source property, and add sources inside function loop like that:

```
let source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: fileDescriptor, eventMask: fsEvent, queue: queue)
sources.append(source)
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is not here because the second both of the above methods are reassigning `source`. However the second one works.